How to display a daterangepicker in embedded mode
How can you display a double calendar with the daterangerpicker in embedded mode
I want to display it as the example presented here : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html
It works very well with the classic datepicker.
Thanks for your help.

Could you show how your code looks and describe how the output differs from what you expect?

$('#datepicker').daterangepicker();
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
$('#my_hidden_input').val(
$('#datepicker').daterangepicker('getFormattedDate');
)
})

Solution :

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2
    })
    $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
        $('#my_hidden_input').val(
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
        )
    })

